# Android WebRTC Failed to send TURN message, err=22

Tags: android, webrtc, error-list

Trying to send a text message after update my application to support 64-Bit using native library of **WebRTC** (`libjingle_peerconnection_so.so` to arm64-v8a)
the messages **passed** to the receiver but the logcat print bunch of error messages any idea?

logcat output of the sender device:

```
E/libjingle: (apm_helpers.cc:67): Failed to set AGC mode in ADM: 1
E/libjingle: (adm_helpers.cc:47): Unable to set recording channel to kChannelBoth.

E/libjingle: (adm_helpers.cc:65): Failed to set stereo recording mode.
E/libjingle: (adm_helpers.cc:109): Failed to set stereo playout mode.
E/libjingle: (webrtcsession.cc:1319): AddSctpDataStream called when sctp_transport_ is NULL.

E/libjingle: (stunport.cc:506): sendto : [0x00000016] Invalid argument
E/libjingle: (turnport.cc:724): Jingle:Port[0x5596dbe130:data:1:0:relay:Net[lo:127.0.0.0/8:Loopback]]: Failed to send TURN message, err=22

E/libjingle: (stunport.cc:506): sendto : [0x00000016] Invalid argument
E/libjingle: (stunport.cc:282): Jingle:Port[0x559704fe00:data:1:0:local:Net[lo:127.0.0.0/8:Loopback]]: UDP send of 96 bytes failed with error 22

E/libjingle: (turnport.cc:724): Jingle:Port[0x5596dbe130:data:1:0:relay:Net[lo:127.0.0.0/8:Loopback]]: Failed to send TURN message, err=22

E/libjingle: (stunport.cc:506): sendto : [0x00000016] Invalid argument
```

Comment: I am having the same issue, that is happening sometimes while connecting/disconnecting few times in a row. On web side it keeps on iceconnectionstate checking.

Have you found any solution for that?

Comment: I have same issue :( any update?

Comment: @forlayo I solved problem. but it is so case dependent. these messages are too common errors. Here is a check list
1. your turn server is running, 2. test your turn server https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/

Comment: Did you solve it? Same issue.